# Rails 5, Postgesql and grouping by association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm struggling to get my head around Postgesql and grouping by association.

I have a trial which has_many repetitions. I want to group by a column in repetitions to use in a variable. Currently i have:

```
@trials = Trial.joins(:repetitions).group('repetitions.repetition_index')
```

But get this error.

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "trials.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Now from reading up about this i need to include `trials.id` in my group method, but when I do the output isn't grouped by `repetitions.repetition_index` anymore. It seems as though it groups by `trials.id`.

How do I go about making sure that group is only by `repetitions.repetition_index`?

**Update**

Trying:

```
@trials = Trial.joins(:repetitions).select('repetitions.repetition_index,repetitions.treatment_index').group('trials.id, repetitions.repetition_index,repetitions.treatment_index')
```

And calling:

```
<% @trials.each do |r| %>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td><%= r.repetition_index %></td>
            <td><%= r.treatment_index %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

Gives me an output of:

```
|1|1|
-----
|1|2|
-----
|2|1|
-----
|2|2|
-----
```

When I'm looking to get:

```
| |1|
|1|2|
-----
| |1|
|2|2|
-----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of this error you can do

```
@trials = Trial.joins(:repetitions).group('trials.id, repetitions.repetition_index')
```

If you don't want to group by `trails.id` and want to group by `repetitions.repetition_index` you have to select only repetitions.repetition_index from query like

```
@trials = Trial.joins(:repetitions).select('repetitions.repetition_index').group('repetitions.repetition_index')
```

Let me know if you are clear or not

**Update**
As per your updated question i think you need something like below. query isn't tested . let me know if its not working

```
 Trial.
 joins(:repetitions).
 select('repetitions.repetition_index,repetitions.treatment_index').
 group_by {
    |repetition| repetitions.repetition_index
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal. Understand all that. But I also want to include another column in the repetitions association called: treatment_index. To include this in the group seems to undo the repetitions.repetition_index grouping, thats what I'm struggling to understand.

Comment: Then you have to group with parent table, in your case, trails. I don't think it will affect your result. did you try it?

Comment: That also seems to ignore the repetitions.repetition_index group if I include trials.id into the group method.

Comment: You can also "uniq" method of array, after fetching results from query

Comment: @DollarChills Try to add both `trails.id, repetitions.repetition_index` in group

Comment: It spits out an array, once called it produces the repetition_index then displays [#<Trial id: nil>, #<Trial id: nil>]

Comment: It should create response like `{:1 =>  [#<Trial id: nil>, #<Trial id: nil>], :2 => :1 =>  [#<Trial id: nil>, #<Trial id: nil>]}`

Comment: an inspect gives me: 1 [#<Trial id: nil>, #<Trial id: nil>] 2 [#<Trial id: nil>, #<Trial id: nil>]

Comment: So that seems correct. But what are the #<Trial id: nil> referring to and how do I call treatment_index?

Comment: Get an error when trying to call treatment_index: undefined method `treatment_index' for 1:Integer

Comment: You need to map attributes of that record, Trial.
 joins(:repetitions).
 select('repetitions.repetition_index,repetitions.treatment_index').
 group_by {
    |repetition| repetitions.repetition_index
  }.map(&:attributes)

Comment: undefined method `attributes' for [1, [#<Trial id: nil>, #<Trial id: nil>]]:Array... they dont make it easy!

Comment: You have to map attributes for #<Trial id: nil>, first get that value and apply map attributes , you will get all attributes which are exists in record

Comment: Thanks for your help @Vishal I have it all sorted now.